# Extracting x and y co-ordinate from G_code data

Tags: python-3.x

My Code:

```
import math
file1=open("g_code.nc","r")
for lines in file1:
    lineList=lines.split()
    if 'X' and 'Y' in lines:
        data=str(math.floor(float((lineList[1][1:]))))+" "+str(math.floor(float((lineList[2][1:]))))+"\n"
        file2=open('test.txt','r')
        lastline=file2.readlines()[-1]
        if data!=lastline:
            file2.close()
            file2=open("test.txt","a")
            file2.write(data)
            file2.close()
file1.close()        
file2.close()
```

Can someone give a better idea to solve this problem,
I want to get the value of X and Y excluding decimal values.
Note that I dont want same values in successive lines but it is fine for them   to come after few different values.

Input file contains data in the form:

```
G2 X-1.1269 Y-14.4111 I0.0267 J0.027 F60   
G2 X-1.1269 Y-14.4111 I0.3267 J0.267 F6  
G2 X-3.1269 Y-1.4111 I0.0467 J0.067 F50  
G2 X-1.1269 Y-14.4111 I0.067 J0.07 F70
```

Output should be:

```
-1 -14  
-3 -1  
-1 -14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you'd use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to find the number. And usually, you wouldn't reopen and close the file for each write operation. Something like this (not tested):

```
import re
numbers = []

def append_if_different(x, y):
    if not numbers or (x, y) != numbers[-1]:
        numbers.append((x, y))

with open("g_code.nc","r") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        matches = re.findall(r'[XY]([-+]?\d+)', line)
        if len(matches) == 2:
            append_if_different(int(matches[0]), int(matches[1]))

with open("test.txt", "w") as outp:
    for xy in numbers:
        outp.write("{} {}\n".format(*xy))
```